# Configure where Vim breaks long lines

Tags: vim

How does Vim determine where to break lines when they exceed `textwidth`, and how can I control this behavior? For example, typing

```
a = really_long_function_call(some_super_long_parameter_name_that_i_want_wrapped
```

with `set textwidth=72` results in

```
a =
really_long_function_call(some_super_long_parameter_name_that_i_want_wrapped
```

when what I want is to supply more sophisticated logic that would break the line on the opening parenthesis of the call, e.g.,

```
a = really_long_function_call(
        some_super_long_parameter_name_that_i_want_wrapped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained at `:help 'textwidth'`:

> Maximum width of text that is being inserted.  A longer line will be
>     broken **after white space** to get this width.

To get around this, you'd have to write a function that performs the text break, and install it via the `'formatexpr'` option. I haven't seen this used so far, and the help is also shy on this, so some effort is required here.

Note that for visual-only, soft wrapping, you *can* influence where it happens, via `:set wrap linebreak breakat=...`

Comment: Thank you. `:set formatexpr=<some_function>` looks like what I need. Now I just need to figure out how to write the `<some_function>`.

Comment: Yeah. As I said, I've no experience with this, and so far haven't found an example. Good luck, and please post your findings!